# Android Studio Internet Permission

Tags: android, android-studio

I decided migrate my application from eclipse to android studio, but when I run it's throwing the SecurityException with permission denied, and suggest I'm missing the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

But the permission is on it. And I can't figured out how to fix it.

My AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.brmobile.boo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

Comment: Who and when throws? `Android Studio` or your android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the Android Studio each module (library project on eclipse), have your own Manifest. So, I include the permission on my Volley Manifest and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your android version is too high, the version higher than 6.0(API 23) need to add runtime permission, you could use Andriod 4.0 to try the code.

Comment: This question is from 2014, API 23 doesn`t exists yet.